# Win32api for serial communication in excel VBA

Tags: python-3.x, vba, excel, serial-port, pyserial

I have data acquisition devices I would like to pull information from.  I've started a small project in Python 3.5 using pyserial to communicate to a device.  I can send commands and receive data.

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = 'COM1'
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.parity = PARITY_NONE
ser.timeout=.5
ser.open()
ser.write(b'#02\r')
print(ser.readline())
ser.close()
```

This sends a command to retrieve data in the buffer, and when I use the readline command, I pull in data.

```
b'>-999999-999999-999999-999999                     -999999\r'
```

I've created an excel sheet to host data tables and test criteria which I am judging performance of our machines on.  This was initially for manual user input, but I decided I'd try and see if I can automate this directly in excel.  I've poured over several webpages, found several companies that would ask for payment for code- etc.  I've finally settled on work done by [The Scarms](http://www.thescarms.com/VBasic/CommIO.aspx) which uses the WIN32API to deal with serial I/O vs. the original mscomm32.ocx driver.

I've been able to bring his files into my project, and used the sample code to start.  I can send a message, and visually verify it from the device I'm communicating through, but I don't get any reply from my end data acquisition device.

```
strData = "#02\r"
lngSize = Len(strData)
lngStatus = CommWrite(intPortID, strData)
```

The variable strData is a string.  When sending a message using pyserial, it's prefaced by "b" which (to my knowledge) signals it to be encoded to bits before sent through the serial port.

I've been trying to look through the modCOMM code that gets added to VBA from the code provided by the link above, but I can't seem to get an input at all.  Am I sending the information incorrectly using the WIN32API?

How do I send this command over the bus properly in order to get a response from the end device?

The end device in question is an Advantech ADAM 4017+.

Comment: IMHO stick with Python, and wrap it in a COM class which is callable from VBA, http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/01/calling-python-class-using-vba-with-com.html

Comment: Thanks.  I'll check it out.  I do have one question based on the link given- in the post s/he states that win32com needs to be installed.  For this process, they state to download it via pip through visual studio.  Is there a significance going through Visual Studio to get these packages instead of using PowerShell and the pip command?

Comment: the `pip` command should serve either through VS or powershell.